# Is it possible to populate a drop down list with data pulled from ANOTHER drop down list in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Using Google Sheets i am trying to build a search function in one tab that would grab information from multiple other tabs and showcase all that information in one spot.

The information consists of basic text, numerical data, as well as drop down lists.

I can already work with the text and numbers that is stored by using VLOOKUP, but in terms of the drop down lists, is there a way i can pull the data from that dropdown list, and have it show in the searches own drop down list?

I have made attempts to use VLOOKUP already, but it will just return blank and not actively show anything, even when putting the VLOOKUP value as the value for a custom drop down list.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

You asked for:

> Is it possible to populate a drop down list with data pulled from
> ANOTHER drop down list in Google Sheets?

In your new drop down, choose `Drop-down (from a range)` pointing to the older drop-down range.

[image]

Comment: Only problem with that is that its getting SPECIFIC information.

Whereas im trying to utilize VLOOKUP to allow for this dropdown list to get info on what is being searched for, and then pull the correct information from the multiple other tabs.

What you had suggested sadly doesnt work.

Comment: Please share a test sheet.